# Windows PHP 64-bit or 32-bit

Tags: php, windows, iis, fastcgi, windows-server-2016

I want to install PHP on Windows 2016 Server Standard 64-bit OS, but I am confused as there is no FastCGI available for PHP 7.x only 5.x

Should I manually install PHP 7 64-bit or 32-bit on IIS ? 
Or should I use the old FastCGI with PHP 5.3 which is 32-bit?

Comment: Definitely do not go for 5.3 as this is deprecated and out of date version of php. Use 5.6 at least if you have to use 5.x. Many functions do not work in 5.3 and many new ones were introduced in 5.6 what makes this version of php closer to 7.x functionality-wise.

Comment: "there is no FastCGI available for PHP 7.x only 5.x" is incorrect. The same FastCGI setup can be used for PHP 7.x, just like the answer below revealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php-cgi.exe` is included as standard in the [PHP Binaries](https://windows.php.net/download/). You just need to set up a [FastCGI handler mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/fastcgi/#003a) in IIS once you've downloaded and unzipped the PHP binaries.